# Awk argument list too long, but only if I increase the data in the variable

Tags: bash, variables, awk, arguments

I wrote a working bash script that loops over some files to read their plain text, modify it with `sed` and replace a string in a template file with the modified text.
I achieved this by getting rid of `sed` for the replace part (I found quite difficult using it for multiline substitution in my specific case).
`awk` worked fine until now, when I'm trying to increase the number of paragraph in a file (from 200 to 225). I'm getting the error `script.sh: line 11: /usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long`, and the template file is now chopped way before (Opening, 14 paragraphs, Closing) than when it was working (Opening, 200 paragraphs, Closing).

Why does this happen? How can I solve it, possibly keeping `awk`?
Why does `awk` print only 14 paragraphs now, instead of the 200 it could print before?
Why doesn't `set -e` stop the script after that error appears?

This it the script that works until a file becomes too big:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

cp template.bkp template.txt

for file in text/* ; do
    modifiedText=$(sed '...' $file | fold -w 50 -s)
    modifiedText+="

#REPLACESTRING"
    awk -v modifiedText="$modifiedText" '{gsub("#REPLACESTRING", modifiedText, $0); print}' template.txt > template-tmp.txt && mv template-tmp.txt template.txt
done
awk '{gsub("#REPLACESTRING", "", $0); print}' template.txt > template-tmp.txt && mv template-tmp.txt template.txt

[...]
```

The template file looks like this:

```
Opening

#REPLACESTRING

Closing
```

Comment: Your operating system has a limit on how long the combined size of all the arguments to a command can be, and you are reaching that limit with `awk -v modifiedText="$modifiedText"` ...`.

Comment: Agree with above, this isn't an `awk` problem, but a "size of the OS cmd-line" problem. Better to redirect working output into tmp file, then process the tmp file with `awk`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter any idea how?

Comment: `echo "First line" > /tmp/myFile ; while read line ; do echo "$line" >> /tmp/myFile ; done < inputFile` would be one way. You can probably rewrite your whole process as one `awk` program. Work thru parts of [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) , and post a new question with you best attempt to solve the problem, along with a small set of sample input, the required output from that input, your current output and any error messages. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format correctly as `code/data/output/errMsgs`. Good luck

Comment: Perhaps explain what are you trying to do, not just your solution.  After a quick read it looks like you're appending a number of files and adding a header and footer.  If so, it's better to revert the operations.

Comment: @karakfa thank you. Any idea about the 14 paragraphs and `set -e` questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick read it looks like you're appending a number of files and adding a header and footer. If so, it's better to revert the operations

```sh
tempfile=$(mktemp)
sed '...' text/* | fold -w 50 -s >> "$tempfile"    
sed -e '/#REPLACEMENT/ {' -e "r $tempfile" -e 'd' -e '}' template > output
rm "$tempfile"
```

`sed` can operate on multiple files, no need to loop through.  Also use `bash` as the orchestration of operations and keep text in files and do text processing with tools like `awk` and `sed`, which you did partially.